# rxjs/angular4 observable optimization

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an optimisation issue on observables:

I have a two controls that accept an username and password. When the value of the password field changes (with a debounce), I want to call a service method that returns an observable of the query results and I fill a model with those values.

The returned observable throws an exception in case of service error. But I want to just fill the model with an empty array in such a case.

My original implementation:

```
  this.passwordControl.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(500)
    .filter(_ => this.usernameControl.valid && !this.usernameControl.pristine)
    .map((password) => new RequestAuthentication(this.usernameControl.value, password))
    .mergeMap(auth => this.orgService.getOrganizations(auth))
    .catch(_ => {
      return Observable.of([]);
    })
    .subscribe(orgs => {
      this.organizations = orgs;
    });
```

The drawback is that when the catch function is executed, I return a finite observable that completes the stream and I can't listen anymore to the changes.

My solution is to nest observables as such:

```
this.passwordControl.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(500)
  .filter(_ => this.usernameControl.valid && !this.usernameControl.pristine)
  .map((password) => new RequestAuthentication(this.usernameControl.value, password))
  .subscribe(auth => {
    this.orgService.getOrganizations(auth)
      .catch(_ => Observable.of([]))
      .subscribe(orgs => {
        this.organizations = orgs;
      });
  });
```

But this doesn't seem very reactive... How should I do to avoid these nested observables and keep the code clean ?

Comment: Why don't you catch exceptions in `orgService.getOrganizations` instead ? This way you won't break your first snippet flow

Comment: More than a year go I experimented with rxjs retry/fall back on cached value. You can take a look at https://github.com/ipassynk/angular2-learning/blob/master/src/app/http-rxjs/http-rxjs.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general calling `subscribe()` inside another `subscribe()` isn't recommended because you're just exchanging "callback hell" with "subscribe hell". Also you're loosing `error` and `complete` signals from the parent Observable chain. Nonetheless, you can always avoid it.

So if you don't want to end the chain when an error occurs there're a few operators that can help you. Specifically: [`retry()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry) and [`retryWhen()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen) (also [`onErrorResumeNext()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/onErrorResumeNext.ts)) and probably more.

If you don't want to do anything when an error signal occurs use `retry()` instead of `catch()`:

```
.mergeMap(...)
.retry()
.subscribe(orgs => {
  this.organizations = orgs;
});
```

If you still want to be able to perform some side-effect (notify user or whatever) use `.do()` before `retry()`:

```
.mergeMap(...)
.do(null, e => ...)
.retry()
.subscribe(orgs => {
  this.organizations = orgs;
});
```

Comment: won't retry trigger another request but with the same arguments (that are invalid) ?

Comment: The `retry()` operator just resubscribes to its source Observable. What does it mean is up to you. You can use for example `Observable.defer()` to be able to create a different source Observable based on some conditions or you can use `Observable.create` for the same reason.

Comment: It does work with retry, it was really unclear to me from the documentation, marked as solved, thanks!